# Why does calling the "find" method on my model result in this error: "Object of class App\Post could not be converted to int"?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Aspiring PHP dev here trying to learn Vue/Laravel. I'm in the middle of Brad Traversy's "Laravel from Stratch" video series, and I'm running into an issue accessing my model (called App\Post) with Eloquent using `Post::find`.

Here's the class declaration:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'posts';
    // Primary Key Field (id)
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

...and here's the `show` method in my controller (I used the `--resource` flag when creating my post controller, and I set up the routes using `Route::resource` in my routes folder.)

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $post <- Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->with('post',$post);
}
```

When I try to load localhost:8888/posts/$id, I get an error saying that "Object of class App\Post could not be converted to int" with the error coming from the `$post <- Post::find($id);` line in my `show` method. Any ideas on what I could do to resolve this error? Thanks!

Note: I'm using Laravel version 5.6 on top of MAMP (macOS) w/ PHP version 7.2.7

Answer (score 3):

Obviously line:

```
$post <- Post::find($id);
```

is completely wrong. You should use here assignment operator like so:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
```

If in your series there was really `<-` here, I would recommend to change tutorial you are using.

Comment: Good catch!  Just a silly mistake on my end - I've been using R a lot recently. Thanks for your help!